# issue storing price list using ArrayList

Tags: java, list, selenium, webdriver, price

I am having problem storing the price into array list and then display it. I want to store the value of each shirt then find out if its sorting out properly. can't even get the data to be stored.

```
<li class="clearfix">
<a class="products-block-image content_img clearfix" href=".....=product" title="">
<div class="product-content">
<h5>
<p class="product-description">...</p>
<div class="price-box">
<span class="price">$55.51</span>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

I also tried with By.className("price"), but no luck.

```
List<WebElement> myList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".price"));

      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

      for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){  
          list.add(myList.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector(".price")).getText());
          System.out.println(myList.get(i).getText());
      }
```

Comment: what's the error that you face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already added elements having class `price` to your `myList` then `myList.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector(".price"))` won't return any elements;

so change following line :

`list.add(myList.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector(".price")).getText());`

To `list.add(myList.get(i).getText());`

Comment: Awesome Bro, just tried out the code. I have been trying since last night. didn't know what was wrong. 


$55.51
$25.50
$31.00
$30.50
$16.40
$28.98
$16.40

Comment: Great; I'm glad It helped you. Cheers!!